# Convergence of GLMM vs GEE

Tags: glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

I am tring to figure out an issue which bothers me for quite some time, maybe you can help me understanding it. I wrote a SAS program to simulate the power (power analysis) for an experiment, where I have two groups (Treatment and Control), for treating some eye condition. Each subject will contribute both eyes, and therefore the observations are NOT independent, and the outcome is binary: 1 = success, 0 = failure. Under the prior assumptions regarding the probability of success in both groups, and regarding the correlation within a subject, I used some theory of probability to calculate the probability for each of the following events (for each group): Right eye succee and left eye success,
Right eye succee and left eye failure, Right eye failureand left eye success, Right eye failureand left eye failure; Using these probabilities, I have simulated data. I did this 1000 times, and for each dataset, I ran a model to obtain a P-value, and then the power (for a given sample size) was the number of significant P-values out of 1000.
And now for my question. I tried to model the data using both GLMM and GEE. While GLMM performed reasonably (only a few single models did not converge), GEE didn't, and a relatively large number of models did not converge (still the majority did). What I wanted to know, is why this has happened. Why in GEE around 100 out of 1000 did not converge, while for GLMM less than 10.